# Make iframes content overflow outside iframe extents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have a webpage that contains an `iframe`. Inside that `iframe` is an embedded Youtube video. When I play this video I make it scale up (grow) in size. As the video grows, not all the video is visible because the iframe is not wide enough.

Is it possible to make the iframe 'Overflow its content', ie make the video visible outside the iframe width (please see below screen captures for a clear example of what I am trying to achieve).

This is how the webpage currently looks:
[image]

This is how I would like to make the video look when it has fully grown:
[image]

Note I just cant make the iframe wider. I've tried giving the iframe (and all its child elements) the CSS `overflow: visible` but it doesn't change anything.

This is a simple example of how the webpage is arranged:

```
....head, opening html tag, etc. up here
<body>
  <div id="outerContainer" style="overflow: visible">
     <div id="navBar">...</div>
     <div id="content style="overflow: visible">
        <iframe src="myHelpDocumentation.html" style="overflow: visible">
           
           <!-- Inside this iframe/webpage are the embedded Youtube videos.
                Each video is an iframe itself (that sits inside a div). -->

        </iframe>
     </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Do you know of a way using CSS or HTML to show the video outside the iframe extents?** I could potentially use Javascript to remove the video(iframe) from the iframe and place it in the main webpage but this would be very bad website design dont you think?

Comment: use a new window and append the video to it, then maximize it .. because you cannot overflow contents out of a frame without another container

Comment: @CME64 Thanks for the comment. When you say new window, do you mean new popup window, new document, create a div and append it to the end of the parent document, what exactly?

Comment: window.open().. check this for reference http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

Comment: @CME64 Making a popup window isn't a solution. As usual the boss wants an elegant solution. Wants it to look like the iPad video functionality - grow to a specific size and then play.

Comment: let me do some tests and examples for you

Comment: it is not possible to overflow outside of iframe. do absolute positioning for your iframe when you want to expand your video.

Comment: if you are not using jquery tell me so that I can modify my code in the solution

Answer (score 8):

No, it isn't possible...

The document from `iframe` is a completely another document, and the browser security will not let you to do this...

**Edit**: you can use `fullscreen` property using transparent background color for container and put there your embedded video.

The fullscreen code was described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17418879/1420197).

Comment: it is possible, please check my code before saying that, I was convinced it was impossible an hour ago !

Comment: @CME64 Basically you use `fullscreen` property, not what OP asked.

Comment: well, you're right, but the fullscreen solution is what he should consider, otherwise it is a new window and he doesn't want that for sure as it was my first suggestion. if his problem was that the video is smaller than the frame, he should consider re-sizing the video container's dimensions.

Comment: I hit an idea: he can use a transparent color! So, +1 for your post.

Comment: and +1 for your suggestion

Comment: @CME64 I think that this is the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16163089/1420197

Comment: I already did that manually inside .fullScreen and tried in body too, no luck

Answer (score 3):

**[updated and Edited]**

window.open works fine for IE ( *as in `window.open('iframe.html','','fullscreen=1,channelmode=1');` but I want to find a proper way for IE **so that it doesn't reload the contents** as I did for the others*)
but I found you a better way that works on chrome, safari and FF since they don't support theater mode,

your iframe should be like :

```
<iframe src="iframe.html" allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

this is the content page of your iframe:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
.fullScreen{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.minScreen{
    width:auto;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.10.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        var element = document.getElementById('container');
        var maxed = false;
        $('#max').click(function(){
            if(maxed){
                if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.mozCancelFullScreen(); 
                    element.className = "minScreen";
                    maxed = false;
                } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
                    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
                    element.className = "minScreen";
                    maxed = false;
                }
            }else{
                if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
                    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
                    element.className = "fullScreen";
                    maxed = true;
                } else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
                    element.className = "fullScreen";
                    maxed = true;
                }
            }
        });
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <button id="max">click to maximize/minimize</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

you can supply that with css to correct the containers height and width, using classes (addClass and removeClass) when maximized or minimized/closed **(style added to the code)**

IE compatibility function is on the way ..

**EDIT:** maybe you should look at the problem from another angle if you don't want to use windows or fullscreen.

the solution would be *discarding the iframe* which is restricting the accessibility and *replacing it with a div* that has css `overflow:hidden` and then populate this div with your iframe page's contents (you can use ajax or any other method to load the contents). tada, you have something like an iframe but it is an element of the same document. then, you can control the overflow in two ways:

1- toggle the container's css between `overflow:hidden` and `visible` or `auto`.

2- relocate the element outside the container div and use absolute positioning to show it over other elements.

note: don't be afraid of losing the scroll bar, you can build your own or just link your *top* css of the contents with the jquery ui slider's value with *absolute* content's positioning and you are good to go.

Comment: thanks for the code. But isn't simpler to just append the video `div` to the outer document? Ie, `$("#myVideo").append($("#myOuterDocument").body).css("position", "absolute").css("top", "150px");`. This was my fallback solution but I am worried its not good website development practices - removing divs from iframes and inserting them into other webpages.

Comment: yes this can be the only way if you are not using fullscreen nor window, I thought of it, but then I thought of how to select the element from within the iframe given that it is a different document that contains it. I didn't test that theory but here you are telling me all about it.

Comment: FYI, here is the compatibility table of Full Screen API http://caniuse.com/#feat=fullscreen

Answer (score 1):

The other way not suggested here would be to use two iframes. The second would float over the first one and would contain video. You can communicate between windows with [`window.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage). But if you have control over iframe and top page then you could put the video in `div` in top page. Still both pages can communicate with `window.postMessage`.