# Fotorama transparent background

Tags: jquery, css, fotorama

I'm using the Fotorama slider plugin, where you can open an image in fullscreen. I need the background to be transparent, but I can't seem to change it.

You can see what I mean by clicking on [this link](http://www.clauson-kaas.com/rwd/Our-services/Quality-control) and open one of the images in the small slider in full screen.

I have tried to change all background in the slider to the following:

```
background: rgba{0,0,0,0);
```

Comment: for me setting it on `.fotorama--fullscreen`, which i see you already have in comments in your CSS, works (*it is just that the page has almost nothing in the space around the image so it shows just white or the search box occasionally*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It is possible** - I figured it out myself with the following code:

```
.fullscreen .fotorama--fullscreen {
    background: transparent !important;
}

.fullscreen .fotorama__wrap {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7) !important;
}

.fullscreen .fotorama__img {
    top: 0px !important;
    width: 50% !important;
    height: auto !important;
    margin: auto !important;
    left: 0px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about this part of code :

```
.fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__nav, .fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__stage {
    background: #000;
}
```

But you can't set it to transparent, you can set it to white. Or you can add a specific image instead.

**EDIT**

You can't set it to transparent because you enter in a **fullscreen mode** and by default, the background is set to **black**. You can change this color by every color you wants but you will never see the content of your site behind that way.

See this post on SO :

[Background/element goes black when entering Fullscreen with HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163089/background-element-goes-black-when-entering-fullscreen-with-html5)

Comment: I've added `.fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__nav, .fotorama--fullscreen .fotorama__stage {
    background: url(http://www.clauson-kaas.com/cgi-files/transparent.png) !important;
}`

But it didn't make any difference

Comment: Right, my answer was unclear but I explain it a bit better. In fact,with this plugin, you enter in a fullscreen mode. See my updated answer

Comment: Check fotorama options to change this behaviour : http://fotorama.io/customize/options/

Comment: Your answer isn't valid. I figured it out. I have made a new answer.

Comment: Yes I've checked what you change in the code. I've tried that myself with firebug but it didn't works. Maybe it's more easy to debug when you can play with the real code instead of with the inspector.